# Usage of a user Account in an org

Tags: metadata, salesforce-id

Is there a way to quickly find out if a user(Username/Email) in sales force is being used in any of the classes /apex jobs/tasks . Need to understand usage of a user we need to Inactivate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse IDE then there you can do a Global search using `ctrl + E` using Id, Name or email.

Else in developer console > Edit> it gives you option for a global search.
[image]

Comment: @VidyaRani if it help you solve the problem then you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Chrome extension called "Salesforce advanced Code searcher" to your Chrome
[image]

By Clicking on Setup you can see this,here you can search your code